# can't run xfce4-settings-manager after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xfce

As subject, from terminal I get this message:

```
xfce4-settings-manager: symbol lookup error: xfce4-settings-manager: undefined symbol: xfce_dialog_show_help_with_version
```

Comment: Perhaps a similar problem that helps to solve it https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=29965

Comment: Is it possible that prior to the upgrade you were running the 4.10 or 4.12 PPA? Perhaps you need to re-install some Xfce libraries, like `exo`.